# You must be home by 7 o'clock

Tags: grammar

In the following example of mine, is it possible to substitute "until" for "by" or not?
- You must be home **by** 7 o’clock.
I guess until doesn't work here.

Comment: Meanwhile I need to know in the following examples which one is not correct and why?
-1- Why you (hadn’t) come (until) 12 o’clock?
-2- Why you (hadn’t) come (by) 12 o’clock?
-3- Why you (didn’t) come (until) 12 o’clock? 
-4- Why you (didn’t) come (by) 12 o’clock?

Comment: @helix, thanks, and to answer to your comment I have to say yes, it is my own question, but I guess I cannot add similar context to one old question of mine or someone else. Though that id just my own imagination. If I can do that please let me know and I will ask it there. Moreover I have more that 10 similar questions. Can I ask them there too or I have to make different topics? Thanks again. :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding this context to [your other question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/how-to-use-by-and-until-in-these-specific-contexts) since both have the same subject: the difference between "until" and "by."

Comment: Thanks and I need your answers to my questions there Helix. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must be home **by** 7 o’clock

You're correct, substituting *until* won't work there. However, I could say:

> You must not leave **until** 7 o'clock.

Both *by* and *until* set deadlines of sorts: Your sentence means:

> "If you're not home at 7, then be home ***before*** 7."

My sentence means:

> "If you're not leaving at 7, then leave sometime ***after*** 7."

Comment: Or: You have **until** 7 o'clock to go home.

Comment: I'd say that "You must be home until 7 o’clock." is a valid sentence. It changes the meaning of "be" from "arrive" to "stay".

Comment: @TecBrat - You could expound upon that in an answer. It's a very interesting and valid point. I'd upvote your answer, just like I upvoted your comment.

Comment: Thanks @TecBrat
So we have:
- You must be home by 7 o’clock. --> which means: "If you're not home at 7, then be home before 7"
- - You must be home by 7 o’clock. --> which means: "You must stay at home up to 7 o'clock, but then you can leave the home". Am I right?
Meanwhile I wonder if you interpret the negative sentences too. I mean:
- You mustn't be home by 7 o’clock.
- You mustn't be home until 7 o’clock.

Comment: @A-friend - _You must be home by 7 o’clock. --> which means: "You must stay at home up to 7 o'clock, but then you can leave the home". Am I right?_ Not quite _You must be home **until** 7 o’clock. --> means: "You must stay at home up to 7 o'clock, but then you can leave the house"._ As for saying it in the negative, I would say: "You mustn't be home **until** 7 o'clock"; _by_ doesn't seem to work very well in the negative.

Comment: Thank you very much @J.R. As usual an excellent response.