# (Up to / until / by) 50% off

Tags: idioms, word-difference, prepositional-phrases

I wonder if someone could tell me which choice works in the following sentence and why the others do not work: (From my point of view, all of these choices work in this context.)

> They have great promotion till January 5th......50% off.
>
> a) up to; b) until; c) by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to is correct. your sentence would look like this

```
They have **a** great promotion, **up to** 50% off.
```

Meaning on different products, discount is between 0 and 50 per cent.

until is also correct, if you change the sentence a bit, although the context changes.

```
They have **a** great promotion **from** January fifth, **till** January 8th, 50% off.
```

the 50% discount is available from January fifth till eighth.

Answer (score 4):

I'll change this sentence a bit.

> They have great promotional offer till January 5. **Up to** 50 percent off.

The preposition *[up to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up+to)* suggests a boundary, here it's 50 percent or less. But surely, not more than 50 percent.

Other words -

> They have great promotional offer till January 5. **Until** 50 percent off -incorrect.

*[Until](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/until)* is used up to the point **in time or the event** mentioned. So you may say *...discount until January 5.* or *...purchase as much as you can until the discount is offered.*

> They have great promotional offer till January 5. **by** 50 percent off -incorrect.

You have asked a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/how-to-use-by-and-until-in-these-specific-contexts) before and mcalex has explained it. Though to add something, we use *by* with *percent* often to compare the previous condition. For instance, *With such a fabulous offer of discounts of 50 percent, their sales raised **by** 50 percent!"*