# The promotion is valid by December 5th

Tags: grammar

1) I need to say the promotion will be invalid on December 6th and while we have not reached that date, the promotion will be valid. What should I say:

> A) The promotion is valid **up to** December 5th. 
>   B) The promotion is valid **until** December 5th. 
>   C) The promotion is valid **by** December 5th. 
>   I think only 'C' is correct here.

2) I need to say the promotion is valid from date ‘X’ to date ‘Y’. After the date ‘Y’ the promotion will be invalid. How shall I say it:

> A) They have great promotion from January fifth, until January 8th up to 50% off. 
>   B) They have great promotion from January fifth, up to January 8th up to 50% off.

For me both work here and have exactly identical meanings. Am I right?

Comment: The first promotion is in effect ***through*** December 5 is the best way to put this. It is in effect *until* or *up to* December **6**. *By* doesn't work here. The second promotion runs from Jan 5 ***through*** Jan 8 if it is still in effect on Jan 8, through Jan 7 if it is not.

Comment: Related: The use of *up to, until and by* from the answers answer this [(Up to / until / by) 50% off](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/up-to-until-by-50-off)

Comment: Another short, informative and perfect response from you @StoneyB. Thank you very much. ;) Just do you agree if using "until" or "up to" in my second question here was possible and correct, but ans boatseller had mentioned, a little ambiguous? :)

Comment: Yes, *until* and *up to* are both correct but ambiguous - do you mean until the end of Jan 8 or the beginning of Jan 8 or until some time in the middle of Jan 8?

Comment: @StoneyB I am well aware that if I need to say until the end of Jan 8, the best way to imply that will be: "through Jan 8" and if I need to indicate the end of Jan 7, then I have to say "through Jan 7". I just needed to make sure whether "up to" and "until" mean the same in that example of mine or not? If yes, then whether they are ambiguous or not? :)
Anyway I owe you a great gratitude as usual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the promotion is valid from right now until 11:59:59 on December 5:

> The promotion is valid through December 5th.

A & B could be used and would likely be interpreted correctly, but they are ambiguous.  C is not correct.

> They have a great promotion from January 5th to January 8th, up to 50% off.

The problem you have here is advertisers will often take liberties to make the phrase as short, and memorable, as possible so correctness is secondary to the message.

Comment: Excellent. :) Thank you @boatseller. Just I wonder if you could clarify the reason why 'A' and 'B' are ambiguous? ;)

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous because a day is a relative long period of time.  Up to Dec. 5. Do the speaker mean to the beginning of Dec 5, which would be Midnight, or does the speaker mean to include Dec 5.  If the speaker want to be very specific, they might say "up to and including Dec 5".

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the correct way to say this is that the promotion is valid "through December 5" or "until December 5".

When we say that an event "will happen by [date]", that means it will happen on or before that date. Like if you said, "Sally will arrive by 8:00", you mean that she will arrive sometime between now and 8:00. Using "by" in this way is normally done only for something that happens once, not something that is ongoing.

Of course "happens once" says nothing about how long the event lasts. But from the point of view of the speaker, it is a single event and not something occurring over a period of time. So you might say, "We need to have another big promotion by the end of August". But you wouldn't say, "The promotion is valid by August" when you are trying to convey that it is good from today (or whatever starting date) through August.